# Increase data insert speed of PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, centos, centos7, postgresql-9.5

I am stuck in a problem that PostgreSQL data writes are very slow.

I developed my application in Java (using JDBC) to insert data into a PostgreSQL DB. It works well on our remote development server. However, after I deploy it to the production server, it causes a problem.

The insert speed of PostgreSQL on the production server is only `~150 records/s for 200000K records`, while it is `~1000 records/s for the same data set` on the development server.

Firstly, I tried to change the configuration in `postgresql.conf` as follows:

```
effective_cache_size = 4GB
max_wal_size = 2GB
work_mem = 128MB
shared buffers = 512MB
```

After I changed the configuration and restarted, it only affects the query speed, while the insert speed does not change (~150 records/s).

I have checked my server memory info, there is a lot of free memory ~4GB. The inserter only uses 0.5% of 8GB (~40MB).

So my questions are:

Is this a problem of a storage disk, such as SSD and HDD or virtual
and physical etc.? Why is the insert speed still very slow, although I have changed the configuration? Is there any way
for increasing the insert speed?

**Note:** the problem does not relate to the insert query structure. 
I have used the same query in the same condition elsewhere (I set up an
environment in 2 servers in the same way). I do not know why the
DEVELOPMENT server (4GB) works better than the PRODUCTION server
(8GB).

Comment: Do you insert one row at a time in a loop in your frontend ?

Comment: Yes, I did, I am considering 1000 data rows with 1000 insert expression compared to 1000 data rows with only 1 insert expression which one is better. However, It looks like using an expression separately easy to control a duplicate inserted data by using ON CONFLICT rather than the other. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only one of your parameters that has an influence on `INSERT` performance is `max_wal_size`. High values prevent frequent checkpoints.

Use `iostat -x 1` on the database server to see how busy your disks are. If they are quite busy, you are probably I/O bottlenecked. Maybe the I/O subsystem on your test server is better?

If you are running the `INSERT`s in many small transactions, you may be bottlenecked by `fsync` to the WAL. The symptom is a busy disk with not much I/O being performed.

In that case batch the `INSERT`s in larger transactions. The difference you observe could then be due to different configuration: Maybe you set `synchronous_commit` or (horribile dictu!) `fsync` to `off` on the test server.

Comment: I haved used `iostat` command to check. The result is: 
PRODUCTION: %user: ~10 %iowait: ~40 %idle: ~40%
DEVELOPMENT: %user: ~10 %iowait: ~16 %idle: ~75%

Comment: wkB/s is totally different: ~1000 wkB/s for PRODUCTIOn and ~5000wkB for DEVELOMENT

Comment: Yes, you are clearly I/O bound. So my answer should help.

Comment: Thank you so much. Now I know what is the problem